# Display UTF8 and ISO-8859-1 in select box HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, utf-8, character-encoding

**Hello, Folks!**

All my script files are utf8, the server responses are utf8, the db collation.. quite everything.

I have a JSON data that populates the options of a select box. When I fix ISO I get in trouble in UTF8, or vice versa.

**The point is:** How can select option display both ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 special chars?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <select id="values" name="values">
        <option>VALÊNCIA 18</option>
        <option>BAHRAIN â€«Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø­Ø±ÙŠÙ†â€¬â€Ž 40</option>
    </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can't. Translate the non-UTF encoded text before putting it in the select box.

Comment: On re-reading the question, I'm not sure where the non-UTF-8 data comes in, since quite everything is UTF-8.

Comment: UTF8 Comes from database collected by javascript that I cant share here.

Comment: So, I will try to translate each non-UTF before putting in the select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SOLVED]** If any one had the same problem as me and the charset was already correct, simply do this:

1. Copy all the code inside the .html file.
2. Open notepad (or any basic text editor) and paste the code.
3. Go "File -> Save As"
4. Enter you file name "example.html" (Select "Save as type: All Files (.)")
5. Select Encoding as UTF-8
6. Hit Save and you can now delete your old .html file and the encoding should be fixed

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible. But as in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_charset.asp this is possible but not supported by any popular browser, and it is obsolete in HTML5, so you should not use it.

As an alternate, you can convert non-Unicode text to UTF-8 using server-side script (PHP, ASP.net,...).
PHP ----> [UTFString= utf8_encode ( ISO_String)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

ASP.NET ----> utf8_encode= Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes(ISO_String);

```
        https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs0350fy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
```

Hopefully you will find this helpful